# 401 error on API over HTTPS, but not over HTTP

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, nginx, axios

I'm trying to link with my mongoDB database, using axios, Vue, and my server is running NGINX.

In my `App.vue` file, where the axios requests are, I have this:

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
      baseApiURL: '[HTTP or HTTPS]://example.com:4000/api',
```

This works over HTTP. When I change it to HTTPS, it doesn't. I have tried using the IP address, and using the domain address. Network tab on Chrome says:

```
Request URL: https://www.example.com/api/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

I don't understand what this means exactly.

My NGINX config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  ssl on;
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /usr/src/app/ssl/domain.cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/src/app/ssl/private.key.pem;

  # vue app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /usr/src/app/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if there's anything else I should include in this info, please let me know. I feel like it should be a small issue as it's working over HTTP.

Comment: Your reverse proxy is using HTTP it is likely trying to access the encrypted connection in an incorrect way

Comment: @AlexW, do you mean I should use https on the proxy_pass? I just tried that but now the error is 502 bad gateway

Comment: Does [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) help? There is an example reverse proxy with SSL.  Just FYI, they are using TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 which I believe are deprecated

Comment: @AlexW unfortunately it doesn't seem like it, I've tried all sorts of various settings but still get errors. It seems the configuration I had in the post with the 401 error is the closest to being correct, somehow

Answer (score 0):

Not really an "answer" as it doesn't solve the exact initial problem, but I solved my problem of my site not working over HTTPS by using Caddy Server instead of NGINX, which somehow does it automatically.